# How to make a process unable to exit by hook sys_exit_group and sys_kill

Tags: c, linux-kernel, kernel-module

I'm working with Android 8.1 Pixel2 XL phone.
I have hooked the sys_call_table and have replaced the syscalls with my own functions using the kernel module.
I want to make an application unable to quit.
I'm trying to invalidate an application's sys_exit_group and sys_kill.
What should I do in my own function.

I want to debug an application, but it turns on anti-debugging. So I want to hook the system call

I have tried direct return, but It wasn't work. System will call sys_kill again.But this time, I can't get the application's uid from its pid.

```
asmlinkage long my_sys_kill(pid_t pid, int sig)
{
    char buff[MAX_PATH] = {0};
    kuid_t uid  = current->cred->uid;
    int target_uid = get_uid_from_pid(pid);
    if (target_uid == targetuid)
    {
        printk(KERN_DEBUG "@Tsingxing: kill hooked uid is %d pid is %d, tragetuid is %d, packagename: %s\n",uid.val,pid, target_uid, buff);
        return 0;
    }
    printk(KERN_DEBUG "@Tsingxing:kill called uid is %d,pid is %d, traget_uid is %d\n",uid.val,pid,target_uid);
    return origin_sys_kill(pid, sig);
}

asmlinkage long my_sys_exit_group(int error_code)
{
    char buff[MAX_PATH] = {0};
    kuid_t uid  = current->cred->uid;
    long tgid = current -> tgid;
    long pid = current->pid;
    int target_uid = get_uid_from_pid(pid);
    if (uid.val == targetuid || target_uid == targetuid)
    {
        printk(KERN_DEBUG "@Tsingxing:exit group hooked, pid is %ld\n",pid);
        return 0;
    }
    return origin_sys_exit_group(error_code);
}
```

Comment: What are you expecting to happen by preventing a function from exiting?

Comment: This is not a good design on at least three different levels: hooking system calls is explicitly not supported by the Linux kernel maintainers, hooking these two system calls is insufficient to cover all of the ways a process can be induced to exit (you would need to hook _all_ paths to [`do_exit`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/kernel/exit.c#L775), including things like kernel-generated SIGSEGV), and making a process unkillable is a bad idea on its face (what if the process malfunctions? you, the user, need the ability to make any process go away, that's why kill -9 exists).

Comment: ... And moreover this smells very much like what we call an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/).  Please explain _why you think you need to make a process unkillable_ and maybe we can work out a better approach.

Comment: I want to debug an application, but it turns on anti-debugging in a thread. So I want to hook the system call. And I know it calls sys_exit_group. Do I need to hook do_exit ?

Comment: Could you explain in more detail what you mean by "anti-debugging"?  Maybe there's a way to prevent it from doing _that_.

Comment: I have solved this problem. I mixed sys_call_table and compat_sys_call_table. The Target application is using compat_sys_call_table but I'm using the __NR_xxx. I solved the problem with using __NR_compat_xxx. Just return direct in compat_sys_call_exit_group

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this problem. I mixed sys_call_table and compat_sys_call_table. The Target application is using compat_sys_call_table but I'm using the __NR_xxx. I solved the problem using __NR_compat_xxx method. Just return direct in compat_sys_call_exit_group.

Answer (score 0):

At a very high level, this **can't work**. When an application calls `_Exit` (possibly/likely at the end of `exit`), it has no path to any further code to be run. These functions are normally even marked `_Noreturn`, meaning that the compiler does not leave the registers/calling stack frame in a meaningful state where resumption of execution could occur. Even if it did, the program itself at the source level is not prepared to continue execution.

If the function somehow returned, the next step would be **runaway wrong code execution**, likely leading to **arbitrary code execution** under the control of an attacker if the application had been processing untrusted input of any kind.

In practice, the libc side implementation of the `exit` and `_Exit` functions likely hardens against kernel **bugs** (yes, what you're asking for is a bug) whereby `SYS_exit_group` fails to exit. I haven't verified other implementations lately but I know mine in musl do this, because it's cheap and the alternative is very dangerous.

Comment: The application calls the sys_exit_group directly, using svc 0. It does't call the funtion exported by libc

Comment: And the anti-debugging thread send a kill signal to the process. I think if I bypass the exit_group and kill, the application will run normally.